# create a new library [b] that pair a repeating key from a library [a] with sum values from a library [a]

Tags: duplicates, set

I am working on a function to create a new library that pairs a repeating value from a library item[a] with the sum of values from a library item[b]. In addition, for a given length n, assign 0 to the unspecified key.

For example d={a:[1, 2, 2, 5], b:[3,2,2,1]}

return d={1:3, 2:4, 3:0, 4:0, 5:1}

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue using either set() or defaultdict() ?

Thanks.

my current progress:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = {}
d['a'] = [1, 2, 2, 5]
d['b'] = [3,2,2,1]
x = list(zip(d['a'],d['b']))
output = defaultdict(int)
for a,b in x:
 output[a]+=b
x = dict(output)
x = dict(output)
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

print (sorted_x)
n= 8
y = dict(sorted_x)
for i, j in dict(sorted_x).items():
 for a in range (n):.........
```

However, I have no clue to assign new pairs in y

Comment: python or c++??

Comment: Sorry. I am using python3

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support duplicate keys in Dictionary.

If you define dictionary like d={**1:1**, 4:2, **1:3**},

then Python will keep only one unique key like d={**1:3**, 4:2}

I think you can use below approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=[(1,1),(4,2),(1,3)] # Use List of tuples to stores all the duplicate keys
output = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in d:
    output[k]+=v
print output
```